# Given a linear form f on vector space L, prove that there exists one-dimensional subspace M such as L is direct sum of Ker f and M

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, direct-sum

Reading my linear algebra professor's lectures I've stumbled upon following question:

Suppose we are given a non-zero linear form $f$ on vector space $L$. 
Prove that there exists one-dimensional subspace $M \subset L$, $dim M = 1$, such as that $L$ is a direct sum of $Kerf$ and $M$:
$$L = Kerf ⊕ M$$

Firstly I dont even really understand the question, after all saying there exists such M for all $f$ at the very least would imply that the $dimKerf = dimL - 1$, which is clearly not true (at least for any given $f$).
Am I missing something here ?

Comment: It is not true for every $f$ but here $f$ is a linear form.

Comment: Pick a point $x \notin \ker f$. Show that every point of $L$ can be written uniquely as $\lambda x + k$ where $k \in \ker f$.